# How to have Python post a file to Slack

Tags: python, csv, slack

I have a Python script that currently posts a link to a slack group chat. What can I change or add to make it drop a CSV file instead of dropping the link to take you to the CSV file. Thank you

```
def post_slack():
    """Post slack message."""
    try:
        token = 'token'
        slack = Slacker(token)

        obj = slack.chat.post_message(
            channel='#dataworksapp',
            text='https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/firebase_results/?project=dataworks-356fa',
            as_user=True,
            attachments=[{"pretext": "Subject",
                          "text": "Body"}])
        print obj.successful, obj.__dict__['body']['channel'], obj.__dict__[
            'body']['ts']
    except KeyError, ex:
        print 'Environment variable %s not set.' % str(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    post_slack()

#post to slack above
```

Answer (score 1):

The `channels` parameter is actually a string, not an array.

```py
client.api_call('files.upload', filename='file.png', channels='#thechannel', file=open('/tmp/file.png','rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this -

```
client.files_upload(channels='#thechannel', filename='file.png', file=open('/tmp/file.png', 'rb'))
```